# Is it more efficient to use the class, e.g. Hashtable than the interface, e.g. Map?

Tags: java, interface

Will the compiler generate better code if it knows the actual class it will be working with vs the interface?

For example, I refer to my actual class like so:

```
Hashtable<String,String> foo() {
    Hashtable<String,String> table = new Hashtable<String,String>(100);
    ....
    return table;
}

...

    Hashtable<String,String> tbl = foo();
```

VS

```
Map<String,String> foo() {
    Map<String,String> table = new Hashtable<String,String>(100);
    ....
    return table;
}

...

    Map<String,String> tbl = foo();
```

Will the first form be more efficient?

---

OK, summarizing the answers now. I wish I could mark both Thomas and Tagir as correct, but I can't.

Thomas is correct in that the "correct" behavior is to use the abstract interface (Map) rather than the concrete implementation (Hashtable). This is the proper abstraction of the data and allows for the underlying implementation to be changed at will.

Tagir is correct in that exposing the concrete class allows certain compiler optimizations -- possibly highly significant optimizations. However, knowing if this will work or not requires knowledge of the compiler internals or benchmarking, and is not portable. It probably does not work for Android.

Finally, if you care about performance, don't use Hashtable; it's obsolete and clunky. If you really care about performance, consider using arrays instead.

Comment: Interface reference will help you for moving to another map implementation without changes in the code.

Comment: The downvotes here seem quite narrow-sighted to me. This is a legitimate question with non-trivial answers.

Comment: Why would anyone use a Hashtable though.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Believe it or not, that's still the only one mentioned in most of today's university curricula. So it's usually a sign of the asker being a student.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, This is a thread-hot environment. (Animation discovers that needed information isn't in the table, so launches a new thread to retrieve it. The missing information appears a frame or two later) so I used Hashtable

Comment: Anyway, my two favorite answers are Thomas who points out that I should take the more general, abstract form, which I agree with, and Tagir who points out that if the compiler knows the actual concrete class being used, it opens up all sorts of avenues to compiler optimization, which I also agree with. But unfortunately, nobody *knows*. Unfortunately, I suspect it depends on the compiler and I would need a compiler writer to chime in here.

Comment: Finally, nope, not a student. Been developing Android and Java for a very long time, and I well know the difference between HashMap and Hashtable and when you would use one vs the other. I'm just a little light on compiler internals.

Comment: I think you have a simplistic vision of the difference between Hashtable and HashMap. There are many more differences than just synchronized methods, and all are in favor of HashMap. Hashtable is nothing but legacy.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Tagir, just like me, implies HotSpot compilers in his answer, which are utterly irrelevant for ART.

Comment: Marko, thanks for prompting me to do some research. I see that Hashtable is no longer considered relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of runtime efficiency both should be equal as in both cases a `Hashtable` is used.

In terms of design using `Map` would be better in most cases, i.e. when it is irrelevant which implementation of `Map` is used. Generally you should use interfaces where possible so that you can replace the implementation, e.g. use a `HashMap` instead.

The difference between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` for example, would mainly be due to thread safety, i.e. `Hashtable` is synchronized and thus threadsafe while `HashMap` yields better performance due to the lack of synchronization. If you'd use `Map` in your interface you could also use `ConcurrentHashMap` without having to change the caller and get thread safety along with performance (although I'm not sure about how much difference there would be between `ConcurrentHashMap` an `Hashtable`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was getting ready to change Hashtable to Map in my code for exactly the reasons you mentioned, but I was worried that it might cost me performance. This is a thread-hot environment, so Hashtable was the one to use, although now that I know about ConcurrentHashMap, I'll probably use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that using `Hashtable` is itself a crime against performance (acquires a lock on each method call), the advantage of using a concrete class will only give a slight advantage to non-JIT-compiled code because the class's *vtable* can be reached directly, as opposed to a linear search through the *itable* lookup array, plus a dereference to the actual *itable*. The overhead of this search would become significant only if a class implemented many interfaces, which is not the case for `Hashtable`.

Unless your call sites dispatch to many different implementations of `Map` (hardly likely), the JIT-compiled code will be as efficent as if you used the concrete type on the variable. And for the simplest case where you say

```
Map<K,V> m = new Hashtable<>();
```

even the interpreter can statically determine that `m` will always point to a `Hashtable` and optimize accordingly.

Comment: I doubt that interpreter optimizes this.

Comment: I didn't check; but it _could_ optimize it based on just the local information provided by the source code.

Comment: This is a thread-hot environment. (Animation discovers that needed information isn't in the map, so launches a new thread to retrieve it. The missing information appears a frame or two later) so I used `Hashtable`. However, `ConcurrentHashMap` also looks like a good choice.

Comment: Also, this is an Android app, and Android switched to non-jit in the most recent releases.

Comment: There is no reason to ever use `Hashtable`. It is an outdated class which is no longer maintained. if you need synchronization, `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` is better.

Comment: Surely you would have to stress in your question that it is ART-specfiic. You cannot expect ART-specific answers on a general Java question, especially since Android isn't really a Java(TM) JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's possible that returning a concrete class may improve the performance. For example, consider that you obtain something from the map:

```
Map<String,String> tbl = foo();
String result = tbl.get(something);
```

In case if `tbl` is the concrete class like `Hashtable` (and you have no `Hashtable` subclasses which overload the `get` method), the call to the method can be easily devirtualized and even inlined (this can be done even by simpler C1 "client" compiler). In case if you use the interface, the it would be harder to devirtualize. As far as I know, C1 cannot devirtualize the interface call with many implementors at all. C2 "server| compiler can do it, but it should rely on type profile. Thus your code should be hot enough and profile should not be polluted with other types.

However while in some specific benchmarks such difference can be orders of magnitude, in most of production code this is negligible and unlikely to be the performance bottle-neck.

Comment: "orders of magnitude", really? The most I've heard is something like 5 times slower on modern HotSpot (given the specific case of a class which doesn't implement thousands of interfaces).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, devirtualized code may be inlined and used for further optimizations like dead code elimination, loop unrolling, vectorization, etc. It's not about the itable search overhead.

Comment: But I assume C2 will always devirtualize both; so the difference can only be in C1, which doesn't perform as many transformations (I admit I don't know much about C1).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, in simple cases C2 can devirtualize both, but in polluted type profile case it cannot. Suppose after getting the map from the `foo()` you pass the resulting map to another method which is used from other places as well. If it's called with different map implementations, then the map methods will unlikely to be inlined. Though probably such scenario is somewhat different from OPs code...

Comment: The polluted type profile implies you're _fundamentally_ prevented from declaring the narrower type, that's why I wouldn't consider it here.

Comment: In the meantime I did some JMH measurements, I was unable to reproduce any performance difference at all, either with `-Xint` or `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`. I was dispatching against a map returned from a static method.